# Why does this python method gives an error saying global name not defined?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a single code file for my Google App Engine project. This simple file has one class, and inside it a few methods.
Why does this python method gives an error saying global name not defined?

Erro NameError: global name 'gen_groups' is not defined

```
import wsgiref.handlers


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from django.utils import simplejson

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def gen_groups(self, lines):
    """ Returns contiguous groups of lines in a file """

    group = []

    for line in lines:
      line = line.strip()
      if not line and group:
        yield group
        group = []
      elif line:
          group.append(line)

  def gen_albums(self, groups):
   """ Given groups of lines in an album file, returns albums  """

   for group in groups:
      title    = group.pop(0)
      songinfo = zip(*[iter(group)]*2)
      songs    = [dict(title=title,url=url) for title,url in songinfo]
      album    = dict(title=title, songs=songs)

      yield album





  def get(self):
    input = open('links.txt')
    groups = gen_groups(input)
    albums = gen_albums(groups)

    print simplejson.dumps(list(albums))



def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                       debug=True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace or at the very least the line where the error occured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an instance method, you need to use `self.gen_groups(...)` and `self.gen_albums(...)`.

**Edit:** I'm guessing the `TypeError` you are getting now is because you removed the 'self' argument from `gen_groups()`. You'll need to put it back in:

```
def get_groups(self, lines):
    ...
```

Comment: It gives TypeError: gen_groups() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) when I added self.

Comment: It's not a class method. It's an instance method.

Comment: @hughdbrown: Python is not my first language, forgive my slightly incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it explicitly with an instance:

```
groups = self.gen_groups(input)
```

Similarly for some of the other calls you're making in there, e.g. `gen_album`.

Also, see [Knowing When to Use self and `__init__`](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11896) for more information.

Comment: It gives TypeError: gen_groups() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) when I added self.

Comment: This error is not going to appear from the code you showed us, where gen_groups is quite clearly defined to take 2 arguments: it follows that you must be running some DIFFERENT code instead.

Comment: No, after I added the self.gen_groups(input), it started giving that error

Comment: Are you saying that the ONLY difference from the code you pasted is the change to self.gen_groups(input)?

Comment: I see the OP's not responding on this thread, but meanwhile he did accept an answer which basically is any use at all only if the code he showed is, as I said, NOT what he was running (specifically his def statement for gen_groups). I rarely ever downvote but I'm sure being SORELY tempted here, given this behavior...:-(

Comment: Alex, agreed.  Your diagnosis was spot on and I'm not sure why the OP responded otherwise.  From his profile, it is amusing that he gives more downvotes than upvotes (6:3)!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use it like this:

```
self.gen_groups(input)
```

There is not implicit "self" in Python.

Comment: It gives TypeError: gen_groups() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) when I added self.